# Error with function argument when using extract function in R

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics, zonal-statistics, extract

I am using the script described [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/254726_caf5ac8c774645d890f97a674f6afa33.html) to try to extract a count of raster cells within polygons in a shapefile. This code worked for me yesterday but today I am getting the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("extract") : 
  no applicable method for 'extract' applied to an object of class "c('RasterStack', 'Raster', 'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"
Error:
! Arguments in `...` must be used.
x Problematic argument:
* fun = sum
```

```
#import required libraries
library(maptools)
library(raster)

#list files (in this case raster TIFFs)
grids <- list.files("D:\\files\\test", pattern = "*.tif$")

#check the number of files in the raster list (grids)
length <- length(grids)

#read-in the polygon shapefile
poly <- readShapePoly("D:\\files\\test\\polygons.shp")

#create a raster stack
s <- stack(paste0("D:\\files\\test\\", grids))

#extract raster cell count (sum) within each polygon area (poly)
for (i in 1:length(grids)){
  ex <- extract(s, poly, fun=sum, na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Hard to help without either your data or some information about it - can you show the basic info of your raster stack and your polygon, such as the extent, resolution etc? It'll be useful too if you can show the version numbers of R and the raster package. If I just try and set up a situation like yours it works for me. The only guess I have at the moment is "Have you created a function called `sum` that is overwriting R's actual `sum` function?". I still can't get your error message though.

Comment: Thank you for the input and feedback about my question... I think I may have found the answer. After loading the "raster" package containing the extract function I was loading the "tidyr" package which also has a function extract and this package was masking the extract function from "raster".

Comment: If its something that's useful to any one else, add it as an answer below and that makes things better! If its not useful, then maybe you can delete the question if you don't think it will ever help anyone else because they are unlikely to do the same thing!

Answer (score 4):

I think I may have found the answer. After loading the "raster" package containing the extract function I was loading the "tidyr" package which also has a function called extract and this package was masking the extract function from "raster".

Comment: In case you don't know, you can specify the library for a function by using `raster::extract(...)`

Comment: Good to know.. thanks for the tip!